# Atom PHP-Linter Setup: System can't find path

Tags: php, atom-editor, linter

I just installed the php-linter for Atom. I'm pretty sure that I configured the path to the php.exe right. But somehow there is still a problem with php-linter. I copied the error code from the console. The German is in English: "The system can't find the given path".

```
(anonymous) @ C:\Users\timsi\.atom\packages\linter\lib\linter-registry.js:159
C:\Users\timsi\.atom\packages\linter\lib\linter-registry.js:159 [Linter] 
Error running PHP Error: Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\timsi\.atom\packages\linter-
php\node_modules\sb-exec\lib\index.js:56:20)
at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:885:16)
at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:334:11)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:501:12)
```

Frome the Atom config:

```
"linter-php":
executablePath: "C:/Program Files(x86)/PHP/php.exe"
```

A screenshot from the path to my php.exe

Path to php.exe

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a simple spelling mistake: in your config, there‘s a space missing between „Program Files“ and „(x86)“